# Objective-c -method in implementation only and extension class's method, what's the difference

Tags: objective-c

I'm an objective-c beginner, and i saw code like below:

**DemoController.m:**

```
@interface DemoController()
-(void)method1;
@end

@implementation DemoController

-(void)method1
{
    NSLog(@"This is method1 in class extension");
}

//this method is not declared in DemoController.h, only in DemoController.m.
-(void)method2
{
    NSLog(@"This is method2 in implementation only");
}

@end
```

I want to know what is the difference between method1 and method2.
Could anyone kindly tell me?

Sincerely,
Huang

Comment: `method1` can be called from another class by the class's object reference but `method2` can only be called from within the class.

Comment: lol i've said the same thing as *Wain* but without specific words such as visibility and scope..

Comment: In DetailViewController.m file, when i call the method1 of DemoController like below:
    [aDemoControllerObj method1];

the compiler report below error: No visible @interface for 'DemoController' declares the selector 'method1'

Comment: @Huang_Hai_Feng Because you surely haven't declared `method1` in your `.h` file.

Answer (score 3):

In older Objective-C versions, you needed to declare a method before you could use it, that's what the first three lines of your code is doing with `method1`. If your `.h` file does not declare either `method1` nor `method2`, neither can be easily called from outside your `.m` file.

In Objective-C, *all methods are public!* There is no way to hide a method. You can always call any method using "low-level" means like `performSelector:withObject:`. But if you declare a method, the compiler gives you the easy access you're used to: `[object method]`.

So there is no difference between `method1` and `method2` in your example. Declaring methods in a class extension so you can use them *in the same file* is not necessary any more.

Comment: I see, but i saw methods declared in class extension, what's the use of class extension methods?

Comment: As I wrote, in earlier version it was needed to declare a method when you needed to call it before you could define it. Imagine `method1` would call `method2` and vice versa, then you would need to declare one or other before you can define it. You can also use it to declare additional methods in separate header files (like you would do with a named class category, like `@interface Foo(Bar)`). The advantage of a class extension is that you don't need a special `@implemention Foo(Bar)` block.